# If someone puts an item at another anvil, will the price reset?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

If someone puts an item in another anvil than the one where it was repaired or renamed, will the price reset?

Comment: Definitely no, the amount of repairs are stored on the item itself and not on the anvil.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the price is determined by the item not by the Anvil.

You can calculate the costs using this [calculator](http://badrouter.net/anvilcalc/) for example.

Further information for the costs can be retrieved from [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Anvil_mechanics#Unit_repair).